# Custom model in c ++ doesnt update ListView on QML side

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I'm building GUI to control my ADC, connected to the STM32 board. Communications are handled by UART. Everything works fine. The problem is to properly handling my custom channel structure as a model object to be able to present data in different ways depending on the delegate object.

I have tried a few different solutions,  none of them works. The case looks trivial however is a little different than presented examples on the forum  or in tutorials on the web because I'm trying to update the data model from c++ side, not from qml. That forces me to invoke setData() override method to be invoked on c++ side and propagate dataChange() signal into qml. Let's present some code.

[image: screenshot]

That's how the app presents the data models after initialization. This data are provided in SensorList constructor. No matter what I tried, I can not change those values on qml side. Even when I confirmed using debugger that vector of my channels in sensorList is changing when data are received from sensor. This looks like a problem with communication between C++ and QML.

My data handler.

ADS8588h.h

```
#ifndef CHANNEL_H
#define CHANNEL_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QString> 

class AdsChannel  {
  Q_GADGET
  Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name  )
  Q_PROPERTY(double value READ value  )

 public:
  AdsChannel(const QString& channelName, const double value)
      : mName{channelName}, mValue{value} {}

  AdsChannel() = default;
  AdsChannel(const AdsChannel& rhs) = default;
  AdsChannel& operator=(const AdsChannel& rhs) = default;

  void setName(const QString& name) { mName = name;}
  void setValue(const double value) { mValue = value; }


  const QString name() const { return mName; }
  double value() const { return mValue; }


 private:
  QString mName;
  double mValue;

};

 Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(AdsChannel);
#endif  // CHANNEL_H
```

SensorList.h which collects list of channels

```
#ifndef SENSORLIST_H
#define SENSORLIST_H

#include "AdsChannel.h"

class SensorList : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SensorList(QObject *parent = nullptr)
    { 
        mItems.push_back(AdsChannel("CH1",5.0));
        mItems.push_back(AdsChannel("CH2",55.0));
        mItems.push_back(AdsChannel("CH3",0.0));
        mItems.push_back(AdsChannel("CH4",0.0));
        mItems.push_back(AdsChannel("CH5",0.0));
        mItems.push_back(AdsChannel("CH6",0.0));
        mItems.push_back(AdsChannel("CH7",0.0));
        mItems.push_back(AdsChannel("CH8",0.0));
    }

    QVector<AdsChannel> items() const
    {
        return mItems;
    }

    bool setItemAt(int index, const AdsChannel &item)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= mItems.size())
            return false;

        const AdsChannel &oldItem = mItems.at(index);
        if (item.name() == oldItem.name() && item.value() == oldItem.value())
            return false;

        mItems[index] = item;
        return true;
    }

private:
    QVector<AdsChannel> mItems;
};

#endif // SENSORLIST_H
```

SensorDataModel.h

```
#ifndef SENSORDATAMODEL_H
#define SENSORDATAMODEL_H


#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include "AdsChannel.h"
#include "SensorList.h"

class SensorList;

class SensorDataModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(SensorList *list READ list WRITE setList)

public:
    explicit SensorDataModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    enum {
        NameRole = Qt::UserRole +1 ,
        ValueRole
    };

    // Basic functionality:
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = ValueRole) const override;

    // Editable:
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value,
                 const int role = ValueRole) override;

    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) const override;

    virtual QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;

    SensorList *list() const;
    void setList(SensorList *list);

private:
    SensorList *mList;
};
#endif // SENSORDATAMODEL_H
```

SensorDataModel.cpp

```
#include "SensorDataModel.h"
#include "SensorList.h"

SensorDataModel::SensorDataModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent)
    , mList(new SensorList)
{
}

int SensorDataModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    // For list models only the root node (an invalid parent) should return the list's size. For all
    // other (valid) parents, rowCount() should return 0 so that it does not become a tree model.
    if (parent.isValid() || !mList)
        return 0;

    return mList->items().size();
}

QVariant SensorDataModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid() || !mList)
        return QVariant();

    const AdsChannel item = mList->items().at(index.row());
    switch (role) {
    case NameRole:
        return QVariant(item.name());
    case ValueRole:
        return QVariant(item.value());
    }

    return QVariant();
}

bool SensorDataModel::setData(const QModelIndex &indexModel, const QVariant &value,const  int role)
{
    // indexModel is empty as this method is invocable from c++ side. Index which is given in dataChange() signal is calculated
    // based on index data which are updated

    //When data arrived from a sensor this how this method is invoked.
    //mData.setData(QModelIndex(),QVariant::fromValue<AdsChannel>(temp),SensorDataModel::ValueRole);


    if (!mList)
        return false;

    auto newElement = value.value<AdsChannel>();

    const auto listElements = mList->items();

    AdsChannel item;
    int indexFinder = 0;
    for(indexFinder ; indexFinder < rowCount(); ++indexFinder)
    {
        if(newElement.name() == listElements.at(indexFinder).name()) {
            item = listElements.at(indexFinder);
            break;
        }
    }
    switch (role) {
        case NameRole:
            item.setName(newElement.name());
            break;
        case ValueRole:
            item.setValue(newElement.value());
            break;
        }

     if (mList->setItemAt(indexFinder, item)) {
        emit dataChanged (this->index(indexFinder,0), this->index(indexFinder,0), QVector<int>() << role);
         //This signal is emited but never reached on QML side
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

Qt::ItemFlags SensorDataModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return Qt::NoItemFlags;

    return Qt::ItemIsEditable;
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> SensorDataModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> names;
    names[NameRole] = "channelName";
    names[ValueRole] = "value";
    return names;
}

SensorList *SensorDataModel::list() const
{
    return mList;
}

void SensorDataModel::setList(SensorList *list)
{
    // I never use a setList() as my list is initialized throw constructor.
    beginResetModel();

    if (mList)
        mList->disconnect(this);

    mList = list;

    endResetModel();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "ads8588h.h"
#include "SensorList.h"
#include "SensorDataModel.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  ADS8588H driver ;
  qmlRegisterType<ADS8588H>("AdsDriver", 1, 0, "AdsDriver"); // Used to some other features

  qmlRegisterType<SensorDataModel>("SensorModel", 1, 0, "SensorDataModel");
  qmlRegisterUncreatableType<SensorList>("SensorModel", 1, 0, "SensorList",
      QStringLiteral("SensorList should not be created in QML"));

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("sensorList"), driver.getSensor()->list());

  const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
  QObject::connect(
      &engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated, &app,
      [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl) QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
      },
      Qt::QueuedConnection);
  engine.load(url);

  return app.exec();
}
```

QML code using simple TEXT label to eliminate some potential bug using CANVAS, requestPaint() signals and other.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

import SensorModel 1.0

Item {
    id:root
    anchors.fill: parent

        ListView {
            implicitWidth: root.width * 0.8
            implicitHeight: width
            x:root.width/2 - width/2
            y:170
            id: customList
            focus: true

            spacing: 4
            snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
            highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
            highlightMoveDuration: 250
            orientation: ListView.Vertical
            boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds

            model:   SensorDataModel{
                list: sensorList
                onDataChanged: console.log("ss") //<-- This signal never appear
            }

            delegate:   Item{

                width: parent.width
                height: width * 0.2

//                ChannelProgressBar{
//                    id:licznik
//                    anchors.fill: parent
//                    labelSuffix: suffix
//                    labelChannel: model.channelName
//                    progressValue: model.value

//               }
                Row{
                    spacing: 20
                    Text{
                        id:label1
                        font.pixelSize: 40
                        text: model.channelName
                    }
                    Text{
                        id:label2
                        font.pixelSize: 40
                        text: model.value
                    }
                }

           }
       }
}
```

So my question is What im doing wrong that qml did not updated data even when dataChanged() signal is emitted.

Comment: I would test any custom model with this: https://wiki.qt.io/Model_Test

Comment: I think you have an inversion problem: shouldn't the `AdsChannel` be changed and then signal that it changed, which in turns is listened to by the `SensorList` and/or `SensorDataModel`?

Comment: hyde I use that test as you suggest but nothing happens, no warnings or fatal errors occur. 

 
Amfasis I see what you mean. But it isn't like that model is holding a pointer to my custom list and through that pointer is managing of individuals channel properties. After an updated operation, model should send dataChange() signal to inform qml it should refresh data in listView?

Comment: Please, somebody, help me :)  I was rebuilding this simple example a few times using different approaches from the web. I'm struggling with this problem  1 week.

Comment: *"I never use a `setList()` as my list is initialized throw constructor."* ok, but what if your list is updated externally ? how do you update the model then ? also not related but you want your model editable but your delegate does not allow it.

Comment: Are you sure whatever `driver.getSensor()->list()` returns is the same list you're actually updating afterwards (however that update happens... which isn't shown, and which could also be relevant to the problem).